# Is there a medical officer on Deep Space Station K-7 in Star Trek Online

Tags: star-trek-online

My character has been injured in ground combat and I'm looking to be healed by a medical officer like the one at the Earth space station. (It costs no credits, using items to do it does.)

**In short, is there a medical officer on Deep Space Station K-7?**

I can't find one. And if there is not, where is the nearest medical officer?

Comment: This question is now out of date since there's a doctor present right in sick bay, the first place anyone will look. I doubt anyone will come looking for this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's now a doctor right in sickbay. This question is now pretty silly.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it.  [here](http://stowiki.org/wiki/Deepspace_K7#NPCs) is a list of NPC's that you can find on K-7.  Although, the list may or may not be incomplete.

[alternate link](http://stowiki.org/Deepspace_K7)

Comment: Yay for cited info! Although I believe this is the link you were looking for: http://stowiki.org/Deepspace_K7 (Yours took me to the wiki "page not found".)

Comment: hmm.  Not disputing your error, but I can follow my link :D